# Can't get a JSON back from POST - Incompatible block pointer types

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I wrote a POST method that needs to return a jSON to the viewcontroller that called her.
If i add in the success block `return _jsonDictionary;` I will get this error:

`Incompatible block pointer types sending 'id (^)(NSURLRequest *__strong, NSHTTPURLResponse *__strong, __strong id)' to parameter of type 'void (^)(NSURLRequest *__strong, NSHTTPURLResponse *__strong, __strong id)'`

I guessing that because it's asynchronous, adding a return will force it to be synchronous but, I want all my POST methods for my app to be in one class so getting the data out of the JSON to variables that are declared across my app using something like `valueForKey` makes things a bit complicated for me. 
Is that bad design?

```
    -(NSDictionary *)getData
    {   
        _jsonDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/getSomething",MainURL ]];

        [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];

        AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:nil parameters:nil];    

        AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
        {
            _jsonDictionary = JSON;

            NSLog(@"jsonDictionary: %@",_jsonDictionary);
        }
        failure:^(NSURLRequest *request , NSURLResponse *response , NSError *error , id JSON)
        {
            NSLog(@"request: %@",request);
            NSLog(@"Failed: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
        }];

        [httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
}
```

Another question, why do I get this warning at the end of the above code: `Control reaches end of non-void function` even if i change the name of the method in .m and in .h to `-(void )getData` ??

Answer (score 1):

If your main concern is to "get back" your data, you have three ways (maybe more, but I can only things of those three):

1. in your `getData` method, you can post a `NSNotification` that your viewController subscribed to before calling `getData`
2. if you are using (or plan to use) a dataManager as a singleton, your viewController can KVO on the @property of the dataManager
3. my favorite: in your calling viewController, you construct and pass a block to your `getData` method that will be called (with or w/o the result). This is exactly what you are doing when building the `AFJSONRequestOperation` in your example.

Comment: Interesting. Another question, why do I get this warning at the end of the above code: `Control reaches end of non-void function` even if i change the name of the method to `-(void *)getData` ??

Comment: can't answer as the end of your `getData` method is missing but you are certainly returning something. the compiler is looking at the return type of `getData` *and* at what the method is actually doing.

Comment: Hmm, no, that's the end of the method. Weird.

Comment: I'm returning to my question after a while and I would love to see a code example of your favorite solution to pass a block to another method.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is correct. The block is not supposed to return anything, and your `return _jsonDictionary;` is trying just that.

What you need to do is update `_jsonDictionary` inside the success block (like you already do), and then invoke another function to fire up events that refresh you UI (something like calling `[self.tableView refreshData]`).

Comment: Please read my updated question. I got around 20 POST calls around my app for different classes. I wanted to keep them in one DataManager singleton so updating all the ui from one class around the app seems weird to me. Is that bad design?

Comment: Since you are doing async processes here, there easiest way to “return a value” will be using callbacks. Your `getData` method will return `void`, but will accept a `completion` block and the result will be the first argument of the block. In you VC/Model/whatever, you will provide this block, and do what you need to do with the returned data.

Answer (score 0):

you're totally mixing asyn and sync ... there IS valid no _jsonDictionary that getData could return. the _jsonDictionary is only filled asynchronously when the completion blocks are called.

you need to proceed from there.... call another method for example

---

as for the error/warning you see ... getData is supposed to return something (NSDictionary*) or a void* (almost eqaul to an id)

to not return stuff, it is void only.